# Response.AppendToLog() doesn't append anything in IIS7, Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I'm using Response.AppendToLog to log custom information to IIS Logs under the cs-uri-query field. The logging is working fine on IIS6 but doesn't do anything on IIS7. Do I need to do anything more to get it to work on IIS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to incorrect configuration in Web Config for IIS7. Moving the httpmodule section from system.web to system.webserver solved the logging issue.

Comment: What configuration is needed for logging in web.config? Can you show an example or point to a resource. Thank you.